Anylogic: seized an agent to a certain ressource pool depending on the value of a variable of the agent
I'm working on a project for a company that produces wafers. The goal is to try to find a way to predict the impact of different problems on the wafer's final testing step. To do so I've imagined a model with 5 different types of wafers (Wafer1, Wafer2, Wafer3...) and 5 different types of testers (Tester1, Tester2, Tester3...). Each tester will be able to test some, but not all, types of wafers.
What I did is basically, Create different sources, each one will create a different type of wafer (Source1 will produce Wafer1...). I've created different resourcePoll, each representing a type of tester. What I can't do is to find a way, in the seized block to check the type of wafer entering and to select a resourcePoll available and able to test the Wafer. Each Wafer has a variable called waferType (between 1 to 5). I've found the resourceChoiceCondition option on the seized block but I can't manage to use it. Is there a way to access a resource variable in this option? So I would create a different type of tester with a list of waferType they can test...
Thank you for your answer

Check the "Customize resource choice" tickbox.
In the code box, you now have access to the agent keyword to represent the incoming (seizing) wafer.  And you can use the unit keyword to access each resource pool unit that could be seized, i.e. each tester
If your Wafer agent type has a field myCharacteristic, you could write a choice condition like agent.myCharacteristic == unit.someOtherStuff and bring together what you want.
Writing those conditions depends on your model setup and what exactly you want.  Start simple (VERY simple) and read the help and check some example models to nudge yourself closer. And check here on SOF: Many people before you had this problem :)

when I try to use unit.someOtherStuff (in my case the parameter is "canTest") i have a message saying canTest cannot be resolve or is not a field, are you sure we can access a field using this method

yes, you are using it wrongly. Make sure units are defined to be the agent type that has such a field. Or feel free to open a new issue asking specifically about this :)

The way you are describing the problem you might also be able to use it without using the Customize Resource choice.
Based on your description, your modeling of different Sources, each generating a different type of wafer correct. The creation of several Resource Pools, each representing a tester, is also correct.
You could expand each source block to have its own Service (or Seize) block. On the Service block, you can specify which resources you want to use - and they are an "any one of these sets" (but just one). So if you make Source1 -> Service1 -> Sink1, and on Service1 you add on the "+Add List" button a second option of resource to be used. So, Source1 produces Wafer1 that can use any tester there (even if more than one option, it will use just one option based on availability of testers).
This way you also start according to Ben suggestion (start simple), without requiring any more advanced coding.
